# Issue after removing # from url in angular $locationProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor

In my app.js I have

```
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/views/main.html'
  })
  .when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: 'views/admin.html',
    controller: 'admin',
  })
```

so my routes are localhost:3000/#/ and on click of button it takes me to  localhost:3000/#/admin
I wanted to remove # from my url so I used

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

now `localhost:3000/` is working and on click of button it takes me to `localhost:3000/admin`.

But if I directly give `localhost:3000/admin` in url,it is giving Cannot Get /admin..But if give `localhost:3000/#/admin`,it is taking me to `localhost:3000/admin`.Why this behaviour how can I make `localhost:3000/admin` to work.Can someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move this line

   `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

   before `app.use(app.router);` in app.js file
2. add this line in `javascripts/app.js`

   `$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });`
3. add this code

   `app.get('*', function(req, res) {
       res.render('index', {
          title: 'Express'
       });
   });`

   in `app.js` before `http.createServer(app)` line

Comment: @user7350714 I changed my answer

Comment: oh Man!!!great it is working..what is the mistake here..can u elaborate.So that everyone can get it

Comment: I mentioned these problems above, static import should go before app uses router otherwise you they won't load, to remove hashtag you need to activate html5mode and last one when page refreshes it loads file from backend so you need to send this file for each request

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make all of those routes return the same HTML and other assets, so that the first request to a given URL returns the correct HTML.

With the '#' it's much easier because everything from '#' to the end of the URL is not sent in the request to the server, so the server doesn't have to do anything.

But for urls without the '#' the entire URL is sent to the server so the server has to know what to serve, and the client has to be able to load a correct view depending on which URL was used in the first page load.

With no backend code provided it's hard to tell anything specific, but you have to make sure that:

1. for every request like `http://localhost:3000/admin` the same HTML is returned as for `http://localhost:3000/`
2. you use only absolute URLs in your HTML for CSS and client-side JavaScript
3. your client-side code shows a correct view on the first load
4. your client-side changes the view on every URL change like it did with '#'

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.I understood partically ,but completely blanked on how to implement this.

Comment: I somehow tried to add my code here...Can you please have a look
https://jsfiddle.net/uxj8h3hb/1/

Comment: I cant have the same hml for all the routes..They should be different

Comment: @kaxi1993 .This is the example which I was referring..Can u try u run on your local..This is very small app..U can understand what I was asking exactly..https://github.com/Anomen/AuthenticationAngularJS

Comment: @rsp This is the example which I was referring.This is very small app..U can understand what I was asking exactly..github.com/Anomen/AuthenticationAngularJS –

Answer (score 0):

Please update your html as below:

in the head section , please use 'base' tag.
So head tag will look like something :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
</html>
```

then try using the URL 'localhost:3000/admin'
Let me know if this helps.